# Error handling for automated uploads in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, sync, ftp

Every day I need to upload automatically about 100 images with a total size of 4MB.

I've used ncfttput and FTP via command line, but sometimes the upload of one image gets stuck with a *Connecting to port* message, and so it stops the FTP-upload of the others.

I'm currently using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/giacomo/WRF/DOMAINS/puglia/postprd
ftp -i -n -v <<EOF
open "server"
user "username" "password"
binary
cd /www.example.org/wrf
mput 2mTemp*.gif
quit
EOF

sleep 10

ftp -i -n -v <<EOF
open "server"
user "username" "password"
binary
cd /www.example.org/wrf
mput 850mbRH*.gif
quit
EOF
etc...
```

How could I set a timeout with a consequential retry? Or is there a non-command line method to manage all of this automatically (sync my local folder with my remote folder and take care of any errors)?

Comment: Do you have `rsync` and/or `ssh` access? If not, you can use the `timeout(1)` command to limit the runtime of any given `ftp` attempt. Is there any reason you are reconnecting for each image? Is it because the connection may hang on any given image?

Comment: You could also use `ls` after the `mput` and compare the remote listing with a local one, and repeat the `ftp` if there are differences.

Comment: @zackse, yes, I'm not uploading each *.gif file "all-in-one", but I have divided them in multiple groups because it may hang on any image among the gif files.

Comment: @AFH, I could not use ls in mput since it may get stuck in any image included in mput xxxx*.gif

Anyway I may have solved partially, since I'm using now the passive mode and, unless my upload band is too low, it does not hang anymore.
I will keep you updated

Comment: I've often found passive mode more reliable. I hope this sorts out your problem. I generally use the FireFTP add-on for Firefox when I want to make `ftp` transfers: it is very reliable, and retries when necessary, but it's not suitable for automation. I make regular small automated transfers with the standard Ubuntu and Windows command-line `ftp`: my number and size of files are much smaller than yours, and I have had few problems (I use passive mode).

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved by using the FTP passive mode.
Here is the new FTP command:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/giacomo/WRF/DOMAINS/puglia/postprd
ftp -i -n -v <<EOF
open "server"
user "username" "password"
binary
passive
cd /www.example.org/wrf
mput 2mTemp*.gif
quit
EOF

sleep 10

ftp -i -n -v <<EOF
open "server"
user "username" "password"
binary
passive
cd /www.example.org/wrf
mput 850mbRH*.gif
quit
EOF
etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  For the benefit of others with a similar issue, can you expand your answer to describe what you did?

Comment: Added the word "passive" to my FTP command list